# Unix Pipeling "AWK" - The summation whilst matching

Tags: unix, awk, pipeline

Below I have some raw data. My goal is to match 'column one' values and have the total number of bytes in a single line of output for each ip address. 
For example output:

```
81.220.49.127 6654
81.226.10.238 328
81.227.128.93 84700
```

Raw Data:

```
81.220.49.127 328
81.220.49.127 328
81.220.49.127 329
81.220.49.127 367
81.220.49.127 5302
81.226.10.238 328
81.227.128.93 84700
```

Can anyone advise me on how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Using an *associative array*:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  infile
```

Alternative to *preserve order*:

```
 awk '!($1 in a){b[++cont]=$1}{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (c=1;c<=cont;c++){print b[c],a[b[c]]}}' infile
```

Another way where **arrays** are **not needed**:

```
awk 'lip != $1 && lip != ""{print lip,sum;sum=0}
     {sum+=$NF;lip=$1}
     END{print lip,sum}' infile
```

**Result**

```
81.220.49.127 6654
81.226.10.238 328
81.227.128.93 84700
```

Comment: better replace `$NF` by `$2` to keep it simple and understandable no?